# Changing Connection string from one database to another in c#.net

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I am using connection string in Global.cs which is static.But i want to make change database connection during run time. So I am storing data base name in ini file and am changing it in run time. I wants to point my connection string to the next database which i updated. I am able to fetch that database name from ini file.

I tried to change the connection string db1 to db2. Any one please tell me how can i change that connection String to another database in run time...

```
  iam using Connection string in static Global.cs file that is


   static Global()
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectionStringSettingsCollection getConFromAPP =               ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
            string con = getConFromAPP["DatabseConnection"].ConnectionString;
            conStrYearDatabase = new SqlConnection(con);
            conStrYearDatabase.Open();

        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Console.Write(e1.Message);
        }
    }
```

how to run the same static class file for the second time during run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should not be a tough ask.

- Close the open connection.
- Change your connection string on the existing Connection object.
- Reopen the connection.

  ```
   OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("old conn string>");                
   connection.Open();
   //do somthing with db 1
   connection.Close();

   //Change the connection string
   connection.ConnectionString="<new connection string>";

   connection.Open();
   //do somthing with db 2
   connection.Close();
  ```